# Generate random number with defined number of digits

Tags: ios, random

I want to generate two different random numbers which has 15 digits. How can I do that

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean 15 decimal digits, i.e. a number between `0` and `999999999999999`?

Comment: yes that particular number should have 15 digits

Comment: At most 15 digits or exactly 15 digits?

Comment: exactly 15 digits like 123456789234567

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most random number generating functions such as `arc4random` produce only numbers in
the range `0 .. 2^32-1 = 2147483647`. For a 15 digit decimal number, you can compute
3 numbers in the range `0 .. 10^5-1` and "concatenate" them:

```
uint64_t n1 = arc4random_uniform(100000); // 0 .. 99999
uint64_t n2 = arc4random_uniform(100000);
uint64_t n3 = arc4random_uniform(100000);

uint64_t number = ((n1 * 100000ULL) + n2) * 100000ULL + n3; // 0 .. 999999999999999
```

Or, if you need *exactly* 15 digits:

```
uint64_t n1 = 10000 + arc4random_uniform(90000); // 10000 .. 99999
uint64_t n2 = arc4random_uniform(100000); // 0 .. 99999
uint64_t n3 = arc4random_uniform(100000); // 0 .. 99999

uint64_t number = ((n1 * 100000ULL) + n2) * 100000ULL + n3;
```

Comment: is this upto 15 digits? or exactly 15 digits?

Comment: @iDia: I have updated the answer. (There were some errors first, but I hope that it is correct now.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this::

arc4random() is the standard Objective-C random number generator function. It'll give you a number between zero and... well, more than fifteen! You can generate a number between 0 and 15 (so, 0, 1, 2, ... 15) :
A random number with 6 digits would be:

```
int number = arc4random_uniform(900000) + 100000;
```

it will give random numbers from 100000 to 899999.

Hope it Helps!!

Comment: *"a number between 0 and 15"* is not the same as *"numbers which has 15 digits"* ...

Comment: it was just random number generation. edited answer to get 6 digits. you can change the numbers up to 15 digits. :)

Comment: `arc4random_uniform()` yields (at most) a 32-bit random number, but 15 decimal digits require 50 bits!

Comment: oops!! i didn't notice that. i think then it requires to get 4 digits random number 3 or 4 times and then make them to one number using string to get as many as 15 digits.

Answer (score 0):

using `arc4random()` functionality you can achieve to generate random numbers.

Here is the [link](http://www.tedbendixson.com/iphone-app-development/xcode-random-number-generation-for-iphone-apps/) that will give you pretty good idea about `arc4random()`.
hope this will help